# Create and share actions programatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I am making an app as my uni project, to help users create actions with 0 programming experience.

The problem I've encountered is the following:

- **How do I create a google action programatically**
- **How do I make that action available for user to test?**

*I've looked at resource manager (thinking it could create a new project for that user, and add action to it), but didn't have a lot of success.*

I'm using node.js SDK to do this. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that currently you can't completely create an Actions on Google project programatically.

There are some tasks that you **can** do, however. For example you can:

- [Create a Google Cloud Platform project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project)
- [Update the Actions on Google project information](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/api) including the URL to use for fulfillemnt and making it available for test.
- [Upload source code to Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest) (if you want to use that to deploy your code, although you can deploy it elsewhere)

However, there is no way to make the project an Actions on Google project using the API. Users will need to connect to the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com/) at least once themselves to indicate what Cloud Project should be used for an Actions on Google project.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! Just to clarify, after user grants permissions with OAuth login, I could create a Cloud Platform project, and the only step the user would have to do is to connect it to actions? (If you have a link for that connection page, it would help out a lot as well). 

If you are familiar with voiceflow, they do a similar thing I think, so that's what I am trying to recreate.

Thanks!

Comment: The exact authorization you need depends on how you do it. Using their OAuth credentials, authorized to a valid scope, is certainly one way. I've updated the answer with a link to the Action Console.